# Not able to add value of the matrix to the child of the node three

Tags: c++, oop, matrix, data-structures, tree

I have got a matrix which has random values inside. The values range from `1` to `Width-1`. My decision is to use trees with 4 children per parent (`up`, `right`, `down`, `left`). The `right` function checks if the value of the matrix's cell is less than the `Width+Value`, if yes then it should be possible to save cell's value into the right child of a node iş being holded, then check for the next values recursively. In the end of the recursional process, return to `down`,`left` and `up` functions which work the same way as `up`. The last destionation is `b[HEIGHT-1][WIDTH-1]` point. For Example:

2 1 2
1 2 1
1 1 2

This matrix should fort a tree:
[image]

The code I use has been edited and taken from binary tree.

```
struct node
{
  int key_value;
  node *left;
  node *right;
  node *down;
  node *up;
};

class btree
{
    public:
        btree();
        ~btree();
        void insert(int key); //edit
        node *search(int key);
        void destroy_tree();
        void destroy_tree(node *leaf);
        void insert(int key, node *leaf, int position);

        node *root;
};

btree::btree()
{
  root=NULL;
}
btree::~btree()
{
  destroy_tree();
}
void btree::destroy_tree(node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    destroy_tree(leaf->left);
    destroy_tree(leaf->right);
    destroy_tree(leaf->up);
    destroy_tree(leaf->down);
    delete leaf;
  }
}

void btree::insert(int key)//set root (start point b[0][0])
{

    root=new node;
    root->key_value=key;
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
    root->up=NULL;
    root->down=NULL;
    cout<<"root value"<<root->key_value;
}

void btree::insert(int key, node *leaf, int position) //up 1,right 2, down 3, left 4
{
  if(position==1)
  {
  if(leaf->up!=NULL)
     insert(key, leaf->up,1);
    else
    {
      leaf->up=new node;
      leaf->up->key_value=key;
      leaf->up->up=NULL;    //Sets the up child of the child node to null
      leaf->up->down=NULL;   //Sets the down child of the child node to null
      leaf->up->left=NULL;    //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->up->right=NULL;   //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }
  }
else  if(position==2)
  {
  if(leaf->right!=NULL)
     insert(key, leaf->right,2);
    else
    {
      leaf->right=new node;
      leaf->right->key_value=key;
      leaf->right->up=NULL;    //Sets the up child of the child node to null
      leaf->right->down=NULL;   //Sets the down child of the child node to null
      leaf->right->left=NULL;    //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->right->right=NULL;   //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }
  }
else  if(position==3)
  {
  if(leaf->down!=NULL)
     insert(key, leaf->down,3);
    else
    {  
      leaf->down=new node;
      leaf->down->key_value=key;
      leaf->down->up=NULL;    //Sets the up child of the child node to null
      leaf->down->down=NULL;   //Sets the down child of the child node to null
      leaf->down->left=NULL;    //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->down->right=NULL;   //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }
  }
else  if(position==4)
  {
  if(leaf->left!=NULL)
     insert(key, leaf->left,4);
    else
    {
      leaf->left=new node;
      leaf->left->key_value=key;
      leaf->left->up=NULL;    //Sets the up child of the child node to null
      leaf->left->down=NULL;   //Sets the down child of the child node to null
      leaf->left->left=NULL;    //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->left->right=NULL;   //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }
  }

  else{
    cout<<"ERROR insert node"<<endl;
  }

}

void btree::destroy_tree()
{
  destroy_tree(root);
}

signed short int check;

void up(int b[][WIDTH], int x, int y){ 
    check=y-b[x][y];// check if there is space to go up
    if (check<0){ // if yes
        // go to right() function
    }
    else{ // if there is place recurse and save the pass to the up leaf

    }

}
void down(int b[][WIDTH], int x, int y){}

void right(int b[][WIDTH], int x, int y){ 
    check=y+b[x][y];// check if there is space to go right
    if (check>WIDTH){ // if no go to down function
         down(b,x,y);
    }
    else{ // if there is place recurse and save the pass to the up leaf
        btree::insert(b[x][check], leaf->left, 2);  // save the value of the node b[x][check] into the right child 
        right(b,x,y+check);
        cout<<"value of the node:"<<endl;
    }

}
void left(int b[][WIDTH], int x, int y);

int main(){

    int b[HEIGHT][WIDTH], row, col;
    for (row = 0; row <=HEIGHT-1; row++)
    for (col = 0; col <=WIDTH-1; col++)
    cin >> b[row][col];
    btree start;
    start.insert(b[0][0]);

    return 0;

}
```

I get the error `leaf was leaf was not declared` but leaf->right was ment to send the right leaf of the root (in the beginning), and other children lately.

Comment: It's clear to me why you get "error: ‘leaf’ was not declared in this scope", but since I don't understand what you're trying to do, I can't tell an answer.

Comment: @JohanBoule The right() function checks some parameters of the matrix's cell's value. For ex b[0][2] , if the value is as I need , then I would store the value inside the right leaf of the node I check.

Comment: As far I am able to understand, what you are getting is a compiler error, which was expected since there is no variable named `leaf` in the scope of that function.

Comment: You use `leaf` in `btree::insert(b[x][check], leaf->left, 2);`, in `right()` function. But `leaf` ist't declared in `right()`.

Comment: @max66 I try to use it the same way as it is used in `destroy_tree()` function

Comment: I don't understand your code but... `leaf` is an argument of `destroy_tree()` (the only argument). But the arguments of `right()` are `b`, `x` and `y`. `right()` knowns nothing about `leaf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the solution:

```
btree up;
up.insert(b[x][check], leaf->up, 2, x, y);
```

to create an object.